# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter doesn't show any data on RecyclerView

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

This is my Firestore DB:
[image]

I want to display all items in the `kelas` collection on RecyclerView.

**ClassModel.java**

```
public class ClassModel {
    private String deskripsi;
    private String guru;
    private String nama;

    public ClassModel(String nama, String deskripsi, String guru){
        this.nama = nama;
        this.deskripsi = deskripsi;
        this.guru = guru;
    }

    public String getNama() { return nama; }
    public String getGuru() { return guru; }
    public String getDeskripsi() { return deskripsi; }

    public void setNama(String nama){
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public void setGuru(String guru){
        this.guru = guru;
    }

    public void setDeskripsi(String deskripsi){
        this.deskripsi = deskripsi;
    }
}
```

**ClassAdapter.java**

```
public class ClassAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ClassModel, ClassAdapter.ClassViewHolder> {

    public ClassAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ClassModel> options){
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ClassViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ClassModel model) {
        holder.tvClassName.setText(model.getNama());
        holder.tvClassDescription.setText(model.getDeskripsi());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ClassViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.class_row_item,
                parent, false);
        return new ClassViewHolder(v);
    }

    class ClassViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvClassName;
        TextView tvClassDescription;

        public ClassViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvClassName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClassName);
            tvClassDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClassDescription);

        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding uiBinding;
    ClassAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView rvClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(uiBinding.getRoot());

        rvClass = uiBinding.rvClass;


        setupRecyclerView();
    }


    void setupRecyclerView(){
        Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("kelas");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ClassModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ClassModel>()
                .setQuery(query, ClassModel.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new ClassAdapter(options);
        rvClass.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvClass.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rvClass.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWelcome"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/tvWelcome"
        android:id="@+id/rvClass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/class_row_item"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/main_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lavender"
        app:tint = "@color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After some time of debugging and trials, I found that the culprit was on `activity_main.xml`, which was `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on the RecyclerView. Set different value, say `500dp` or `400dp` then boom all the data is shown. I wonder why.

Comment: So have you solved the issue?

Comment: @AlexMamo Not yet. This is just a test project and currently working on something more important. Will re-visit this issue, though.